# Multiple function in one cell, Microsoft Excel 2003

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to add multiple functions in once cell showing separate answers like e.g.     |

`="Total 1 =>" &SUM(A3:A44)`
`="Count 1 =>" &COUNT(B5:B88)`

All these functions go into one cell e.g. here in cell `A1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just concatenate them together...

```
="Total 1 =>" & SUM(A3:A44) & " Count 1 =>" & COUNT(B5:B88)
```